# yarn.lock file not generated while creating new react file

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, yarnpkg

i wrote create-react-app . in my terminal but yarn.lock file was not produced,. Any help?

while running cmd like yarn install=> it says that yarn is not recognized.

Comment: You need to install `yarn` first

Answer (score 0):

You need to successfully create react app first before running yarn install.